# java: PropertyChangeSupport for Map or EnumMap?

Tags: java, dictionary, event-listener

Is there a version of either [`java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeSupport.html) or [`com.jgoodies.binding.beans.ExtendedPropertyChangeSupport`](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/jgoodies/binding/2.0.2/binding-2.0.2-javadoc.jar!/com/jgoodies/binding/beans/ExtendedPropertyChangeSupport.html) which is helpful for supporting change listeners along the lines of a Map or EnumMap? (a key-value store with known limited keys and change listeners for all the values in the map)

I don't really need beans-type access, I have a number of different statistics sort of like:

```
interface hasName() {
    public String getName();
}

enum StatisticType implements hasName {
    MILES_DRIVEN, BURGERS_SERVED, CUSTOMERS_HELPED, BIRDS_WATCHED;
    @Override public String getName() { return name(); }
}
```

where I want to publish an interface like:

```
interface KeyValueStore<K extends hasName,V>
{
    void setValue(K key, V value);
    V getValue(K key);

    void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener);
    void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener);        
    /*
     * when setValue() is called, this should send PropertyChangeEvents
     * to all listeners, with the property name of K.getName()
     */
}
```

so I could use a `KeyValueStore<StatisticType, Integer>`  in my application.

Is there any convenient way to do this? My head is spinning around in circles and it's sapping my energy trying to reinvent the wheel on this stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless there is a pressing reason not to, I would extend `Map` and use `put` and `get` instead of `setValue` and `getValue`.

I have an interface I often use:

```
public interface PropertyChangeNotification {
    void addPropertyChangeListener(String property, PropertyChangeListener listener);
    void removePropertyChangeListener(String property, PropertyChangeListener listener);
    void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener);
    void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener);
}
```

With that, your interface becomes:

```
interface KeyValueStore<K extends hasName,V>
    extends Map<K,V>, PropertyChangeNotification
{
}
```

Then your implementation winds up looking something like this:

```
public class MyKeyStore<K extends hasName, V>
    extends HashMap<K,V>
    implements KeyValueStore<K,V>
{
    private PropertyChangeSupport changer = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

    public void put(K key, V value)
    {
        V old = get(K);
        super.put(key,value);
        changer.firePropertyChange(key.getName(), value, old);
    }
}
```

Not shown are the 4 methods for the PropertyChangeNotification functionality that simply delegate to `changer`.