# How to reference live Map values

Tags: java, dictionary, reference

I have a `Map` that contains values that I want fast and easy access to. Using `get(key)` can be expensive as the `Map` gets larger. I'd prefer not to `get(key)` every time I need it. But I also want it to be updated with changes to the Map.

```
private int i = get("i"); // This will not be aware of later changes to the Map

private int i() {
    return get(""); // This is potentially slow
}

private Entry<String,Integer> i; // This skips the key-matching part, and is aware of value changes, but unaware of removal
```

I think none of the above 3 options are ideal. What should I do?

Comment: How else are you planning on getting the value? Iterating through the `Map` yourself?

Comment: "Using get(key) can be expensive as the Map gets larger." It shouldn't, if it's a hash map - the point of a hash map is that barring a high number of collisions, it's still ~O(1) access. If you *aren't* using a hash-based map, is there any reason you're not?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Map` that implements a `PropertyChangeListener`, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2548739/3690024).  If your map cannot store `null` values, then removal could be signaled by a property change to `null`.  Or you could implement your own `MapChangeRemoveListener` interface.

In any case, changes would be signaled to any party that has registered interest.  It is not returning a "live" reference to the map value, but at least you don't have to continue to poll the map looking for changed values.